# Why does Google Guava's ArrayListMultimap clear method throw IllegalAccessError when called by method reference?

Tags: java, guava, method-reference

Sample code to demonstrate the failure:

```
package ia.quant.nextgen.entry;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 * Created by arpeke on 2015-12-18.
 */
public final class SampleMain {

    public static void main(String[] argArr) {

        final ArrayListMultimap<Void, Void> arrayListMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        arrayListMultimap.clear();

        final Consumer<ArrayListMultimap> arrayListMultimapConsumer = ArrayListMultimap::clear;
        arrayListMultimapConsumer.accept(arrayListMultimap);
    }
}
```

Here is the `Error` (not `Exception`) I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
    tried to access class com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap
    from class ia.quant.nextgen.entry.SampleMain
at ia.quant.nextgen.entry.SampleMain.lambda$main$1(SampleMain.java:17)
at ia.quant.nextgen.entry.SampleMain.main(SampleMain.java:18)
```

I am using 32-bit Java 8 (v1.8.0_60) with Google Guava v19.0.  My Google-Fu tells me Google Guice is the root cause, but lacks credible explanation.  (This is part of a much larger project that also includes Google Guice v3.0 via Apache Maven.)

Sample ref: https://github.com/hierynomus/scannit/issues/7

Does anyone know...?

1. The root cause
2. A workaround

(Finally, I also tried Google Guava v18.0, but no luck.)

#### Update

This code works, but I don't understand why.  (Do I misunderstand non-static method references?)

```
final Consumer<ArrayListMultimap> arrayListMultimapConsumer = x -> x.clear();
arrayListMultimapConsumer.accept(arrayListMultimap);
```

Comment: FYI: It looks like OpenJDK recently fixed an issue related to this:https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143647

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas need to find the last definition of a method. So when you write `ArrayListMultimap::clear`, the interpreter actually tries to find what class of the hierarchy last defined the method `clear`. It happens that the method is last defined in `AbstractMapBasedMultimap`, which is a package-private class.

The issue at hand is more than likely in the JRE, but two workarounds exist.

The first one is the one that you described. The second would be that the Guava team either makes `AbstractMapBasedMultimap` public or redefines the `clear()` method in `ArrayListMultimap` (and that method would only need to call `super.clear()`).

The easiest of the two workaround for you at this moment is the one you tried. If I were you, I would still ask the Guava team to make their own workaround so that it doesn't impact more users.

Regarding your workaround, it works because you *use* the method instead of *referring* to it.